# How do you get the first two characters of a string?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string `"990822"`. I want to know if the string starts with `"99"`.

I could achieve this by getting the first two characters of the string, then check if this is equal to `"99"`. How do I get the first two characters from a string?

Comment: Have you tried to implement your proposed solution? Getting the first two chars and comparing them against `"99"` doesn't seem so hard.

Comment: I tried some things, but my physical limits makes difficult the things that normal people usually do easily. So I just opted here for some help. I've picked an answer. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`String#start_with?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F):

```
"990822".start_with?("99") #=> true
```

Comment: Based on the answer ids, you posted first ;-)

Comment: You may want to make sure no leading spaces are getting on the way, with string.strip!

Answer (score 4):

Consider using the method [`start_with?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/start_with%3F).

```
s = "990822"
  => "990822"
s.start_with? "99"
  => true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a range to access string:

```
"990822"[0...2]
# => "99"
```

See the [`String` docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

Comment: `[0..1]` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

To get the first two characters, the most straightforward way is:

```
"990822"[0, 2] # => "99"
```

Using a range inside the method `[]` is both not straightforward and also creates a range object that is immediately thrown out, which is a waste.

However, the whole question is actually an XY-question.